# how to output a pandas data frame from a custom function?

Tags: python, pandas, function

I am scraping four different pages from Craiglist that have the exact same structure. To expedite this, I wrote a function that does this, which is supposed to produce a pandas df as a result. I know the functio works because I included print statements inside that produce the output I expect. However, when I try to use the data set that the dunction is supposed to output later in the code, I get an error that reads:

```
NameError: name 'out_df' is not defined
```

Here is the code to my function:

```
#create function to grab the posts
def grab_posts(response, end_value):   
    html_soup = BeautifulSoup(response.text, 'html.parser')
    posts = html_soup.find_all('li', class_ = 'result-row')
#     return posts_i
    print(type(posts))
    print(len(posts))
    #get item description, item price, and listing dates for each item
    items = []
    prices = []
    dates = []
    for i in range(end_value):
        items.append(posts[i].find(class_ = 'result-title hdrlnk').text)
        prices.append(posts[i].find(class_ = 'result-price').text)
        dates.append(posts[i].find(class_ = 'result-date').text)
    print(len(items))
    #create Series from items
    items_col = pd.Series(items)
    #create Series from prices
    prices_col = pd.Series(prices)
    #create Series from dates
    dates_col = pd.Series(dates)
    print(type(dates_col))
    #concatenate
    out_df = pd.concat([items_col, prices_col, dates_col], axis = 1)
    print(out_df.head())
    out_df.rename(columns = {
                0: 'item_description',
                1: 'price',
                2: 'date_listed'
            }, inplace = True)
    print(out_df.head())
    print(type(out_df))
    return out_df
```

It seems like the function works, because the print statements produce what I expect (all the way to printing the data frame). See image below.

[image: Output of the function]

However, a simple command like

```
type(out_df)
```

produces an error that I mentioned above. Can anyone shed some light on why this is happening and how I can get the data frame produces in the function into the memory of my jupyter notebook?

Comment: Suggestion, use `IPython.display.display` rather than `print` to print a `pandas` dataframe

Comment: Did you save your `grab_posts` output to any variable? `out_df` seems only work in function, you can't call it out side of function.

Comment: Something like `out_df = grab_posts(response_1,120)`

Comment: @JimChen he has it inside the function

Comment: If you use `out_df` inside of your function, how did you get that error message?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are calling it outside the function:
You have to assign the return of the function to a variable. Like:

```
out_df = grab_posts(response, end_value)
type(out_df)
```

---

If inside the function:
Try declaring it as global,

```
#create function to grab the posts
def grab_posts(response, end_value):   
    html_soup = BeautifulSoup(response.text, 'html.parser')
    posts = html_soup.find_all('li', class_ = 'result-row')
#     return posts_i
    print(type(posts))
    print(len(posts))
    #get item description, item price, and listing dates for each item
    items = []
    prices = []
    dates = []
    for i in range(end_value):
        items.append(posts[i].find(class_ = 'result-title hdrlnk').text)
        prices.append(posts[i].find(class_ = 'result-price').text)
        dates.append(posts[i].find(class_ = 'result-date').text)
    print(len(items))
    #create Series from items
    items_col = pd.Series(items)
    #create Series from prices
    prices_col = pd.Series(prices)
    #create Series from dates
    dates_col = pd.Series(dates)
    print(type(dates_col))
    #concatenate
    global out_df
    out_df = pd.concat([items_col, prices_col, dates_col], axis = 1)
    print(out_df.head())
    out_df.rename(columns = {
                0: 'item_description',
                1: 'price',
                2: 'date_listed'
            }, inplace = True)
    print(out_df.head())
    print(type(out_df))
    return out_df
```